# Python: Make Copy of List

Tags: python, list, variables, copy, assign

How do I make a copy of a list, so I can edit the copy without affecting the original.  Ex:

```
x = [1., 2., 3., 4.]
y = x
y[0] = 9.
```

The output is:

```
x: [9.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0] 
y: [9.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

when I want x to be:

```
x: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

So how do I make a copy of a variable while keeping the original unchanged?

Thanks in advance,

Eric

Comment: what about `y=x.copy()` in python-3.x...

Comment: `new_list = copy.copy(old_list)` and also `from copy import copy`

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap x with python's list function when declaring y and it works!

```python
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = list(x)
y[0] = 9

print x
print y

#This prints the following
#[1, 2, 3, 4]
#[9, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, in this case, use:

```
x = [1., 2., 3., 4.]
y = x[:]
y[0] = 9.
```

Output for x and y:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
[9.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

But read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list).